# Evaluation error of identity in lubridate::interval objects

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate

Assume a df like this:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(rep(1:5, each = 2)),
time1 = c("2008-10-12", "2008-08-10", "2006-01-09", "2008-03-13", "2008-09-12", "2007-05-30", "2003-09-29","2003-09-29", "2003-04-01", "2003-04-01"),
time2 = c("2009-03-20", "2009-06-15", "2006-02-13", "2008-04-17", "2008-10-17", "2007-07-04", "2004-01-15", "2004-01-15", "2003-07-04", "2003-07-04"))

   id      time1      time2
1   1 2008-10-12 2009-03-20
2   1 2008-08-10 2009-06-15
3   2 2006-01-09 2006-02-13
4   2 2008-03-13 2008-04-17
5   3 2008-09-12 2008-10-17
6   3 2007-05-30 2007-07-04
7   4 2003-09-29 2004-01-15
8   4 2003-09-29 2004-01-15
9   5 2003-04-01 2003-07-04
10  5 2003-04-01 2003-07-04
```

What I try to do, is to, first, create a `lubridate` interval between the variables "time1" and "time2". Second, I want to group by "id" and compare whether the next row is the same as the current and whether the current row is the same as the previous. I can achieve it with:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
 mutate_at(2:3, funs(as.Date(., format = "%Y-%m-%d"))) %>%
 mutate(overlap = interval(time1, time2)) %>%
 group_by(id) %>%
 mutate(cond1 = ifelse(lead(overlap) == overlap, 1, 0),
        cond2 = ifelse(lag(overlap) == overlap, 1, 0))

      id time1      time2      overlap                        cond1 cond2
   <int> <date>     <date>     <S4: Interval>                 <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1 2008-10-12 2009-03-20 2008-10-12 UTC--2009-03-20 UTC     0    NA
 2     1 2008-08-10 2009-06-15 2008-08-10 UTC--2009-06-15 UTC    NA     0
 3     2 2006-01-09 2006-02-13 2006-01-09 UTC--2006-02-13 UTC     1    NA
 4     2 2008-03-13 2008-04-17 2008-03-13 UTC--2008-04-17 UTC    NA     1
 5     3 2008-09-12 2008-10-17 2008-09-12 UTC--2008-10-17 UTC     1    NA
 6     3 2007-05-30 2007-07-04 2007-05-30 UTC--2007-07-04 UTC    NA     1
 7     4 2003-09-29 2004-01-15 2003-09-29 UTC--2004-01-15 UTC     1    NA
 8     4 2003-09-29 2004-01-15 2003-09-29 UTC--2004-01-15 UTC    NA     1
 9     5 2003-04-01 2003-07-04 2003-04-01 UTC--2003-07-04 UTC     1    NA
10     5 2003-04-01 2003-07-04 2003-04-01 UTC--2003-07-04 UTC    NA     1
```

The problem is, as you may see, that for id == 2 and id == 3, both conditions are evaluated as TRUE, even though the intervals are not the same. For id == 1, it properly evaluates as FALSE, and for id == 4 and id == 5, it properly evaluates as TRUE.

Now, when I convert the interval into character, it evaluates it all right:

```
df %>%
 mutate_at(2:3, funs(as.Date(., format = "%Y-%m-%d"))) %>%
 mutate(overlap = as.character(interval(time1, time2))) %>%
 group_by(id) %>%
 mutate(cond1 = ifelse(lead(overlap) == overlap, 1, 0),
        cond2 = ifelse(lag(overlap) == overlap, 1, 0)) 

      id time1      time2      overlap                        cond1 cond2
   <int> <date>     <date>     <chr>                          <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1 2008-10-12 2009-03-20 2008-10-12 UTC--2009-03-20 UTC     0    NA
 2     1 2008-08-10 2009-06-15 2008-08-10 UTC--2009-06-15 UTC    NA     0
 3     2 2006-01-09 2006-02-13 2006-01-09 UTC--2006-02-13 UTC     0    NA
 4     2 2008-03-13 2008-04-17 2008-03-13 UTC--2008-04-17 UTC    NA     0
 5     3 2008-09-12 2008-10-17 2008-09-12 UTC--2008-10-17 UTC     0    NA
 6     3 2007-05-30 2007-07-04 2007-05-30 UTC--2007-07-04 UTC    NA     0
 7     4 2003-09-29 2004-01-15 2003-09-29 UTC--2004-01-15 UTC     1    NA
 8     4 2003-09-29 2004-01-15 2003-09-29 UTC--2004-01-15 UTC    NA     1
 9     5 2003-04-01 2003-07-04 2003-04-01 UTC--2003-07-04 UTC     1    NA
10     5 2003-04-01 2003-07-04 2003-04-01 UTC--2003-07-04 UTC    NA     1
```

The question is, why does it evaluate some intervals as identical, when they are not?

Comment: it seems to me that those **intervals are identical**, but you don't mean to compare the **interval** per se. is there a reason why you create an interval and don't e.g. just `paste` `time1` and `time2` together for your purpose? there are also functions like `duplicated` or `distinct` that might do what you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

If you look at the code for `Interval` classes, you will see that when the object is created it stores the start date and then calculates the difference between start and end and stores that as `.Data`.

```
interval <- function(start, end = NULL, tzone = tz(start)) {

  if (is.null(tzone)) {
    tzone <- tz(end)
    if (is.null(tzone))
      tzone <- "UTC"
  }

  if (is.character(start) && is.null(end)) {
    return(parse_interval(start, tzone))
  }

  if (is.Date(start)) start <- date_to_posix(start)
  if (is.Date(end)) end <- date_to_posix(end)

  start <- as_POSIXct(start, tzone)
  end <- as_POSIXct(end, tzone)

  span <- as.numeric(end) - as.numeric(start)
  starts <- start + rep(0, length(span))
  if (tzone != tz(starts)) starts <- with_tz(starts, tzone)

  new("Interval", span, start = starts, tzone = tzone)
}
```

In other words, the returned object has no concept of the "end date". The default value for the `end` argument is `NULL`, meaning you can even create an interval without an end date.

```
interval("2019-03-29")
[1] 2019-03-29 UTC--NA
```

The "end date" is simply text generated from a calculation that occurs when the `Interval` object is formatted for printing.

```
format.Interval <- function(x, ...) {
  if (length(x@.Data) == 0) return("Interval(0)")
  paste(format(x@start, tz = x@tzone, usetz = TRUE), "--",
        format(x@start + x@.Data, tz = x@tzone, usetz = TRUE), sep = "")
}

int_end <- function(int) int@start + int@.Data
```

Both of those code snippets are taken from https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/blob/f7a7c2782ba91b821f9af04a40d93fbf9820c388/R/intervals.r.

Accessing the underlying attributes of `overlap` allows you to complete the comparison without converting to character. You have to check that `start` and `.Data` are both equal. Converting to character is much cleaner, but if you were trying to avoid it this is how you could do that.

```
ifelse(lead(overlap@start) == overlap@start & lead(overlap@.Data) == overlap@.Data, 1, 0)
```

Taken altogether:

```
df %>%
  mutate_at(2:3, funs(as.Date(., format = "%Y-%m-%d"))) %>%
  mutate(overlap = interval(time1, time2),
         overlap_char = as.character(interval(time1, time2))) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(cond1_original = ifelse(lead(overlap_char) == overlap_char, 1, 0),
         cond1_new = ifelse(lead(overlap@start) == overlap@start & lead(overlap@.Data) == overlap@.Data, 1, 0),
         cond2_original = ifelse(lag(overlap_char) == overlap_char, 1, 0),
         cond2_new = ifelse(lag(overlap@start) == overlap@start & lag(overlap@.Data) == overlap@.Data, 1, 0)) 

id time1      time2      overlap                        overlap_char                   cond1_original cond1_new cond2_original cond2_new
<int> <date>     <date>     <S4: Interval>                 <chr>                                   <dbl>     <dbl>          <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1 2008-10-12 2009-03-20 2008-10-12 UTC--2009-03-20 UTC 2008-10-12 UTC--2009-03-20 UTC              0         0             NA        NA
2     1 2008-08-10 2009-06-15 2008-08-10 UTC--2009-06-15 UTC 2008-08-10 UTC--2009-06-15 UTC             NA        NA              0         0
3     2 2006-01-09 2006-02-13 2006-01-09 UTC--2006-02-13 UTC 2006-01-09 UTC--2006-02-13 UTC              0         0             NA        NA
4     2 2008-03-13 2008-04-17 2008-03-13 UTC--2008-04-17 UTC 2008-03-13 UTC--2008-04-17 UTC             NA        NA              0         0
5     3 2008-09-12 2008-10-17 2008-09-12 UTC--2008-10-17 UTC 2008-09-12 UTC--2008-10-17 UTC              0         0             NA        NA
6     3 2007-05-30 2007-07-04 2007-05-30 UTC--2007-07-04 UTC 2007-05-30 UTC--2007-07-04 UTC             NA        NA              0         0
7     4 2003-09-29 2004-01-15 2003-09-29 UTC--2004-01-15 UTC 2003-09-29 UTC--2004-01-15 UTC              1         1             NA        NA
8     4 2003-09-29 2004-01-15 2003-09-29 UTC--2004-01-15 UTC 2003-09-29 UTC--2004-01-15 UTC             NA        NA              1         1
9     5 2003-04-01 2003-07-04 2003-04-01 UTC--2003-07-04 UTC 2003-04-01 UTC--2003-07-04 UTC              1         1             NA        NA
10    5 2003-04-01 2003-07-04 2003-04-01 UTC--2003-07-04 UTC 2003-04-01 UTC--2003-07-04 UTC             NA        NA              1         1
```

You can read more about `Interval`s here: https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/Interval-class.html

I believe your exact case has to do with the `==` comparison. As you can see above, "overlap" is a list,
not a vector. From ?`==`, it says:

> At least one of x and y must be an atomic vector, but if the other is
>   a list R attempts to coerce it to the type of the atomic vector: this
>   will succeed if the list is made up of elements of length one that can
>   be coerced to the correct type.
>
> If the two arguments are atomic vectors of different types, one is
>   coerced to the type of the other, the (decreasing) order of precedence
>   being character, complex, numeric, integer, logical and raw.

We can coerce "overlap" to both `numeric` and `character` to see the difference.

```
df %>%
  mutate_at(2:3, funs(as.Date(., format = "%Y-%m-%d"))) %>%
  mutate(overlap = interval(time1, time2)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(cond1 = ifelse(lead(overlap) == overlap, 1, 0),
         cond2 = ifelse(lag(overlap) == overlap, 1, 0)) %>%
  mutate(overlap.n = as.numeric(overlap),
         overlap.c = as.character(overlap))

# A tibble: 10 x 8
# Groups:   id [5]
id time1      time2      overlap                        cond1 cond2 overlap.n overlap.c    
<int> <date>     <date>     <S4: Interval>                 <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>        
  1     1 2008-10-12 2009-03-20 2008-10-12 UTC--2009-03-20 UTC     0    NA  13737600 2008-10-12 U…
  2     1 2008-08-10 2009-06-15 2008-08-10 UTC--2009-06-15 UTC    NA     0  26697600 2008-08-10 U…
  3     2 2006-01-09 2006-02-13 2006-01-09 UTC--2006-02-13 UTC     1    NA   3024000 2006-01-09 U…
  4     2 2008-03-13 2008-04-17 2008-03-13 UTC--2008-04-17 UTC    NA     1   3024000 2008-03-13 U…
  5     3 2008-09-12 2008-10-17 2008-09-12 UTC--2008-10-17 UTC     1    NA   3024000 2008-09-12 U…
  6     3 2007-05-30 2007-07-04 2007-05-30 UTC--2007-07-04 UTC    NA     1   3024000 2007-05-30 U…
  7     4 2003-09-29 2004-01-15 2003-09-29 UTC--2004-01-15 UTC     1    NA   9331200 2003-09-29 U…
  8     4 2003-09-29 2004-01-15 2003-09-29 UTC--2004-01-15 UTC    NA     1   9331200 2003-09-29 U…
  9     5 2003-04-01 2003-07-04 2003-04-01 UTC--2003-07-04 UTC     1    NA   8121600 2003-04-01 U…
  10     5 2003-04-01 2003-07-04 2003-04-01 UTC--2003-07-04 UTC    NA     1   8121600 2003-04-01 U…
```

Per the output above, I believe that using `==` is coercing the "overlap" interval to a `numeric` vector, resulting in the duration comparison @hmhensen mentions above. When you force the 
coercion to `character` rather than `numeric`, you get your desired result.

Answer (score 7):

I think it has to do with what `lubridate` is actually calculating.

When I calculate the differences between `date1` and `date2`, this happens:

```
df %>%
  mutate_at(2:3, funs(as.Date(., format = "%Y-%m-%d"))) %>%
  mutate(overlap = time2 - time1)

   id      time1      time2  overlap
1   1 2008-10-12 2009-03-20 159 days
2   1 2008-08-10 2009-06-15 309 days
3   2 2006-01-09 2006-02-13  35 days
4   2 2008-03-13 2008-04-17  35 days
5   3 2008-09-12 2008-10-17  35 days
6   3 2007-05-30 2007-07-04  35 days
7   4 2003-09-29 2004-01-15 108 days
8   4 2003-09-29 2004-01-15 108 days
9   5 2003-04-01 2003-07-04  94 days
10  5 2003-04-01 2003-07-04  94 days
```

So we can tell the intervals are the same in day length.

Now, what is `overlap` actually calculating? To find out I changed your code slightly to report the lead and lag instead of 1.

```
df %>%
  mutate_at(2:3, funs(as.Date(., format = "%Y-%m-%d"))) %>%
  mutate(overlap = interval(time1, time2)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(cond1 = ifelse(lead(overlap) == overlap, lead(overlap), 0),
         cond2 = ifelse(lag(overlap) == overlap, lag(overlap), 0))

# A tibble: 10 x 6
# Groups:   id [5]
      id time1      time2      overlap                          cond1   cond2
   <int> <date>     <date>     <S4: Interval>                   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1     1 2008-10-12 2009-03-20 2008-10-12 UTC--2009-03-20 UTC       0      NA
 2     1 2008-08-10 2009-06-15 2008-08-10 UTC--2009-06-15 UTC      NA       0
 3     2 2006-01-09 2006-02-13 2006-01-09 UTC--2006-02-13 UTC 3024000      NA
 4     2 2008-03-13 2008-04-17 2008-03-13 UTC--2008-04-17 UTC      NA 3024000
 5     3 2008-09-12 2008-10-17 2008-09-12 UTC--2008-10-17 UTC 3024000      NA
 6     3 2007-05-30 2007-07-04 2007-05-30 UTC--2007-07-04 UTC      NA 3024000
 7     4 2003-09-29 2004-01-15 2003-09-29 UTC--2004-01-15 UTC 9331200      NA
 8     4 2003-09-29 2004-01-15 2003-09-29 UTC--2004-01-15 UTC      NA 9331200
 9     5 2003-04-01 2003-07-04 2003-04-01 UTC--2003-07-04 UTC 8121600      NA
10     5 2003-04-01 2003-07-04 2003-04-01 UTC--2003-07-04 UTC      NA 8121600
```

Here, we see that `lead` and `lag` actually calculate the differences in a specific time interval rather than looking at the actual interval start and end dates. That would appear why it sees certain intervals as equal and the character strings as unequal, as they ought to be.

## Some more digging:

Let's take a look at the object produced by `interval`.

```
a <- interval(df$time1, df$time2)

str(a)
#Formal class 'Interval' [package "lubridate"] with 3 slots
#..@ .Data: num [1:10] 13737600 26697600 3024000 3024000 3024000 ...
#..@ start: POSIXct[1:10], format: "2008-10-12" "2008-08-10" "2006-01-09" ...
#..@ tzone: chr "UTC"
```

It's an S4 class with three slots: `.Data`, `start` and `tzone`.

Calling `a` shows us the intervals.

```
a
 [1] 2008-10-12 UTC--2009-03-20 UTC 2008-08-10 UTC--2009-06-15 UTC 2006-01-09 UTC--2006-02-13 UTC
 [4] 2008-03-13 UTC--2008-04-17 UTC 2008-09-12 UTC--2008-10-17 UTC 2007-05-30 UTC--2007-07-04 UTC
 [7] 2003-09-29 UTC--2004-01-15 UTC 2003-09-29 UTC--2004-01-15 UTC 2003-04-01 UTC--2003-07-04 UTC
[10] 2003-04-01 UTC--2003-07-04 UTC
```

But when you performed a calculation on `a`, it did it on `.Data`, which is a sequence of seconds that begin at a specified date (see `?interval`).

```
a@.Data
#[1] 13737600 26697600  3024000  3024000  3024000  3024000  9331200  9331200  8121600  8121600
```

For the start date of the interval, we need to access `start` slot.

```
a@start
#[1] "2008-10-12 UTC" "2008-08-10 UTC" "2006-01-09 UTC" "2008-03-13 UTC" "2008-09-12 UTC"
#[6] "2007-05-30 UTC" "2003-09-29 UTC" "2003-09-29 UTC" "2003-04-01 UTC" "2003-04-01 UTC"
```

And the timezone...

```
a@tzone
#[1] "UTC"
```

We can also look at what the relationships between the elements are. The last and next to last elements had the same intervals.

```
a[9] == a[10]
#[1] TRUE
```

And they're identical objects.

```
identical(a[9], a[10])
#[1] TRUE
```

But what is it really checking when you check to see if the elements are equal? Elements 3 and 4 had the same time difference, but were not the same intervals. Therefore, when you checked to see if their lag/leads were equal, it returned `TRUE`. But since they have different interval dates, they shouldn't be. So when we check if they're identical, only then do we get what we expected.

```
a[3] == a[4]
#[1] TRUE

a[3]@.Data == a[4]@.Data
#[1] TRUE

identical(a[3], a[4])
#[1] FALSE
```

So what happened? What `a[3] == a[4]` really checks is `a[3]@.Data == a[4]@.Data` and therefore it's checking to see if `3024000` equals `3024000`. It does so it returns `TRUE`. But identical checks all the slots and finds that they are not the same because `start` in each are different.

Then I thought about using identical with lead/lag so that we could fit one logical into the code, but look at this.

```
a[9]
#[1] 2003-04-01 UTC--2003-07-04 UTC

# now lead
lead(a[9])
#2003-04-01 UTC--NA
```

The output does not look like `a[10]` as expected.

```
#now lag
lag(a[9])
#[1] NA
#attr(,"start")
#[1] "2003-04-01 UTC"
#attr(,"tzone")
#[1] "UTC"
#attr(,"class")
#[1] "Interval"
#attr(,"class")attr(,"package")
#[1] "lubridate"
```

So `lead` and `lag` have a different effect on class S4 objects. To get a better handle on what your first attempt was outputting, I did this:

```
df %>%
     mutate_at(2:3, funs(as.Date(., format = "%Y-%m-%d"))) %>%
     mutate(overlap = interval(time1, time2)) %>%
     group_by(id) %>%
     mutate(cond1 = lead(overlap),
            cond2 = lag(overlap))
```

I got a lot of warning messages that said

```
#In mutate_impl(.data, dots) :
#  Vectorizing 'Interval' elements may not preserve their attributes
```

I don't know enough about R objects to understand how data in S4 class is stored, but it certainly looks different than the typical S3 object.

Seems like using `as.character`, as you did, is the way to go.

Comment: I think part of the problem with `lead` and `lag` is similar to what I mentioned below for `==`... until someone writes a `lead` or `lag` method for `Interval` class objects, those methods will convert Intervals to a data type that they can handle, namely atomic vectors. I’m also new to R’s OO functionality, but that’s what I’ve taken away from your answer and some of my own searching.

Comment: `lead` is returning `NA` because it looks for the next value in a vector, and you gave it a vector of length 1, so there is no next value in the vector to return (same thing happens with `lead(mtcars$mpg[1])`). What `lead` does with an `interval` object is create a new interval that is equal to the start date of the current record plus the `.Data` value of the next record. You can test this with `lead(a[8:10])[1:2] == c(interval(a[8]@start,a[8]@start + a[9]@.Data),interval(a[9]@start,a[9]@start + a[10]@.Data))`. The NA occurs simply because you have reached the end of the input vector.

Comment: Both of the answers are comprehensive and both of them completely answered my question. Therefore, I gave the bounty to you and accepted the answer of @Wil to honor both of you. Thanks to both of you :)